# libGDX - particle effect tool importing to android studio

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, particle-system

I would like to ask if it is possible to use libGDX particle effect tool if you didn't tick it on project setup at the beginning. I am using AndroidStudio.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Particle-Editor

You can also just open another project and run the particle editor from there since you can export your effects to anywhere you want and the `ParticleEffect` does not depend on anything in `gdx.tools`. Or you could simply import it with Gradle. Just add it to your desktop dependency and re-sync your project.

*build.gradle*:

```
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    }
}
```